# Cygnus JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I installed cygnus and when I hit `sudo service cygnus start` I get the status OK running.

But the log file says:

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -p 8081 -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.7.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

I checked `echo $JAVA_HOME` and get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

I also checked `java -version` and got:

```
java version "1.6.0_35"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.7) (rhel-1.13.7.1.el6_6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

**So what am I missing here?**

I did all these steps here:

> Installing Cygnus
>
> Open a terminal and simply configure the FIWARE repository if not yet
>   configured and use your applications manager in order to install the
>   latest version of Cy gnus (CentOS/RedHat example):
>
> $ sudo cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/fiware.repo <http://repositories.testbed.fi-ware.eu/repo/rpm/x86_64/
>   gpgcheck=0 enabled=1 EOL $ sudo yum install cygnus
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE:
>
> Cygnus, as it is based on Apache Flume, needs Java SDK is installed.
>   If not yet installed, do it right now:
>
> $ sudo yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
>
> Remember to export the JAVA_HOME environment variable. In the case you
>   have installed Java SDK right now as shown above, this would be as:
>
> $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
>
> In order to do it permanently, edit /root/.bash_profile (root user) or
>   /etc/profile (other users).

Comment: have you rebooted after do the export JAVA_HOME... ? Do you execute echo JAVA_HOME after start cygnus?

Comment: Yes I have rebooted, and I echo JAVA_HOME before and after cygnus start its the same

Comment: are you executing the export JAVA_HOME and cygnus in the same terminal window?

Comment: Im not executing it any more because I edited the /root/.bash_profile like so:

`# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH                                            
"~/.bash_profile" 14L, 254C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite such a warning message, Cygus will run since the `flume-ng` (and derived `cygnus-flume-ng`) script looks for Java if JAVA_HOME is not set:

```
# find java
if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ] ; then
  warn "JAVA_HOME is not set!"
  # Try to use Bigtop to autodetect JAVA_HOME if it's available
  if [ -e /usr/libexec/bigtop-detect-javahome ] ; then
    . /usr/libexec/bigtop-detect-javahome
  elif [ -e /usr/lib/bigtop-utils/bigtop-detect-javahome ] ; then
    . /usr/lib/bigtop-utils/bigtop-detect-javahome
  fi

  # Using java from path if bigtop is not installed or couldn't find it
  if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ] ; then
    JAVA_DEFAULT=$(type -p java)
    [ -n "$JAVA_DEFAULT" ] || error "Unable to find java executable. Is it in your PATH?" 1
    JAVA_HOME=$(cd $(dirname $JAVA_DEFAULT)/..; pwd)
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Well Cygnus isn't working, should I edit this code in some file?

Comment: My fault, I wanted to say "Cygnus will run" :) A different thing is why it is not working (btw, did you find the Cygnus logs as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776890/how-to-store-data-in-mysql-using-cygnus?)

Comment: Yes, I opened the log and thought that this was the problem, that's why I posted this question

Comment: Can you print that log? Just in order to confirm if Cygnus is running or not, and if it is running, to try to figure out why it is not working. Thanks!

Comment: I did, its at the top of the page, its the only thing that cygnus.log from `/var/log/cygnus` outputs. Or am I showing you the wrong log?

Nothing else is printed when I send the curl SubscribeContext

Comment: Which is the logging level at log4j.properties? Are you running Cygnus as a service or as a standalone application (the same way you did in the Quick Start Guide)? Anyway, try running this command and print the traces, please: `/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console` (I'm assuming Cygnus it is installed at `/usr/cygnus` and your agent configuration file is `agent_1.conf`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75936/discussion-between-frb-and-vrankela).