# Cygnus didn't update database

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I want to subscribe Orion to send notifications to Cygnus. Then cygnus will save all data in mysql database. I use this script to subscribe the speed attribute of car1.

```
(curl 130.206.118.44:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: vehicles' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /4wheels' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "car",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "car1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "speed",
        "oil_level"
    ],
    "reference": "http://192.168.1.49:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "speed"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

But when I update the speed attribute of car 1, cygnus doesn't update the database.

Databases available:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Some information about my cygnus service and my cygnus configuration (`systemctl status cygnus`):

```
cygnus.service - SYSV: cygnus
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2015-10-21 17:54:07 UTC; 8min ago
  Process: 31566 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31588 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 21 17:54:05 cygnus systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: cygnus...
Oct 21 17:54:05 cygnus su[31593]: (to cygnus) root on none
Oct 21 17:54:07 cygnus cygnus[31588]: Starting Cygnus mysql...  [  OK  ]
Oct 21 17:54:07 cygnus systemd[1]: Started SYSV: cygnus.
```

agent_mysql.conf:

```
# main configuration
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mysql-sink
cygnusagent.channels = mysql-channel

# source configuration
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler

# url target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf


#Orion MysqlSink Configuration
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_grouping = false
# mysqldb ip
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = 127.0.0.1
# mysqldb port
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = 12345
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.table_type = table-by-destination

# configuracao do canal mysql
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

After read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29099334/3018970) question, I changed my agent_mysql.conf in this line:
`cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column` to     `cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row` and restarted the service. Then I updated orion entity and I queried database and nothing happened.

Cygnus log file: `http://pastebin.com/B2FNKcVf`

Note: My JAVA_HOME is set.

Comment: Your configuration seems to be OK. Could you share the entire log of a Cygnus run? Please use gist or pastebin. Regarding the attr_persistence, as you already noticed through the linked question, if you configure it to "column" then Cygnus will not create the table, but it must be provisioned by you. On the contrary, if using "row", it is automatically created by Cygnus.

Comment: @frb I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the logs you posted, there is a problem with the Cygnus log file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/cygnus.log (No such file or directory)
```

After that, Cygnus stops. You must check your configuration regarding log4j, everything is at `/usr/cygnus/conf/log4j.properties` (it should exists, it is created by the RPM... if not existing -because you italled from sources instead of the RPM-, it must be created from the available template). In addition, can you post your instance configuration file? Anyway, which version are you running?

**EDIT 1**

Recently, we have found another user dealing with the same error, and the problem was the content of the `/usr/cygnus/conf/log4j.properties` file was:

```
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
flume.log.dir=./log
flume.log.file=flume.log
```

Instead of what the template contains:

```
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
flume.log.dir=/var/log/cygnus/
flume.log.file=flume.log
```

Once changed it worked because the RPM creates `/var/log/cygnus` but not `./log`.